# Save xaml image as pdf in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am trying to export wpf image as a pdf file. So far I have been successful to export as png file as follow:

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ImageDownload.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageDownload"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ImageDemo" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="DownloadButton" Margin="10" Click="DownloadButton_Click">Download</Button>
        <Image x:Name="canvas" Source="Googlelogo.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**code behind**

```
private void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "Png Image(*.PNG)|*.png";

                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value == true)
                {
                    // Save current canvas transform
                    Transform transform = canvas.LayoutTransform;
                    // reset current transform (in case it is scaled or rotated)
                    canvas.LayoutTransform = null;

                    // Get the size of canvas
                    Size size = new Size(canvas.ActualWidth, canvas.ActualHeight);
                    // Measure and arrange the surface
                    // VERY IMPORTANT
                    canvas.Measure(size);
                    canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

                    // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
                    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
                      new RenderTargetBitmap(
                        (int)size.Width,
                        (int)size.Height,
                        96d,
                        96d,
                        PixelFormats.Default);
                    renderBitmap.Render(canvas);
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                    string extension = saveDialog.FileName.Substring(saveDialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    // push the rendered bitmap to it
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
                    // Create a file stream for saving image
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(saveDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        encoder.Save(fs);
                    }
                    // Restore previously saved layout
                    canvas.LayoutTransform = transform;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I've been seeing some suggestions online to export it as an image file first then export the image file as a pdf file, but I have not been successful to implement it.
Can anyone guide me on how to export the image as a pdf file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22379378/1136211

Comment: Take a look at pdfsharp or google for open source / free pdf generators. Have you thought about just saving it as a png/jpeg and using that? Unless you're also adding text and stuff I don't see what putting a jpeg in a pdf is really adding to a jpeg.

Comment: You ll need some third party library for this purpose ..to export as Pdf.